# JSON Parse error when posting to MEAN API

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, mean-stack

I am currently building a backend for some highschool CS students projects and I cannot for the life of me get posting to work on their end. Everytime a post request is made I get this error:

> Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0

My code that I have given them to post to the API is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        "email": "myEmail@students.berkeley.net",
        "password": "isilly"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        runMySuccessFunction(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failed");
    },
    url: 'https://notmyrealurl.herokuapp.com/veggiegang/api/users'
});
```

Any reason why it isn't working, I'm not the best at Node or Express and I am stumped

Edit: Here is my backend code for the method in use:

```
app.post("/veggiegang/api/users", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("check")
  console.log(req.body)
  const newUser = req.body;
  newUser.createDate = new Date();

  db.collection(VEGGIEGANGUSERS).insertOne(newUser, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to create new user.");
    } else {
      res.status(201).json(doc.ops[0]);
    }
  });
})
```

And just to clarify, the post method in the backend isn't actually running since the JSON parse error happens before it runs. My two console.log statements do not log anything which is why I am saying that. The method also works fine when testing it with ARC, but I cannot get the JS code to work.

Comment: Your code is syntactically valid. There could be an issue with the backend API. Please provide more details or a live code example.

Comment: Just added my code for the method in question from the backend

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending JSON in your request, jQuery converts the data object passed to it into url encoded key=value pairs. To sned JSON you'll have to do the encoding yourself.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "email": "myEmail@students.berkeley.net",
        "password": "isilly"
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        runMySuccessFunction(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failed");
    },
    url: 'https://notmyrealurl.herokuapp.com/veggiegang/api/users'
});
```